# Biased coin randomization with adjustments over time

Tags: experiment-design, weighted-sampling, random-allocation

Assume an experiment that was going to consider different randomization
strategies to address different challenges.  The experiment involves an
experimental (active treatment) and control group (usual treatment).  The
experiment has very little control over the availability of the subjects.  The
subjects are immediately randomized upon eligibility.

Situation 1:  Because there is limited availability of the experimental
treatment, it is necessary to limit the flow of subjects being randomized to
the experimental group.  Thus, we adjust the 50:50 probability -- for example,
40:60 -- and weight the individuals accordingly in the final analysis.

Situation 2:  There are a couple important prognostic factors that may affect the experimental outcomes.  It is still possible that randomization will not produce the proper balance across the prognostic factors.  To address this concern, a biased-coin randomization algorithm is used.

Question:  Is it possible to do both -- that is, control the subject flow and
apply a [biased-coin randomization](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780471462422.eoct370/abstract) algorithm?  This is the only thing I found on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32991/how-to-model-a-biased-coin-with-time-varying-bias), and I am not sure this is the same issue.